# How to correctly split a binary file for parallel decoding

Tags: asn.1, asn1tools

I have a binary file which am successfully decoding sequentially using `asn1tools`, problem is it's consuming some time and am trying to speed-up the process.

my approach was to split binary data using the known starting bytes of the records am looking for.

for example splitting by `bf 4f 80 80` , issue is ... if the date was decoded sequentially we get `x` number for records, say `1000` records, eventhough the file might contain less than `1000` entry that matchs the pattern `b4 4f 80 80`, so if I split the data I always get less than `1000` records as I do in sequential decoding, noting that the file contains single type of data and am sure of the starting bytes

[image]

Comment: dont know if this help but openldap library has a really useful general purpose ber/der encode decode sub library. I used this is a c++ project to read and write ber data.

Comment: First, how do you know multiple parallel accesses to the file will be faster?  If it's on a spinning disk, that will likely be *slower*.  Second, how would you know *where* to split the file?  ASN.1 data is not fixed-length, so you have to read the file to know where to split it.

Comment: @AndrewHenle, looking at binary data gives you a hint on the starting bytes, and to some extent it's working, but am losing some data in the process, trying to figure out how/why

Comment: *looking at binary data gives you a hint* So you're reading the file to figure out where to read the file?

Comment: @AndrewHenle, in the logic, I read the whole file in bytes, then split by starting bytes and then I can decode in parallel, say ... by using thread , each thread can take a chunk and start decoding

Comment: @Exorcismus ASN.1 is basically TLV data - **T**ag-**L**ength-**V**alue.  If you're reading the entire file into memory, parsing TLV data is pretty trivial.  What kind of processing are you doing on the values?  If *that* is what you're trying to speed up, you're already halfway to a multithreaded producer-consumer model - a simple model would be a queue of pointers to the start of each ASN.1 element you want to process.  Start up some processing threads that read from the queue, then have one thread go through the contents and put addresses onto the queue.

Comment: (cont) And since all the pointers are the same size, you can use `pipe()` to create a quick-and-dirty queue - the producer writes the 8 (or 4, or whatever) bytes of each address to the write end of the pipe, and all the consumer threads read the 8-byte pointers from the read end of the pipe.  (This does assume you have C or C++ skills - as @pm100 alluded, a C or C++ tool written just for this task would work pretty fast ....)

Comment: the ldap ber library is c code BTW

Comment: @pm100 OpenSSL also has ASN.1 tools - the [command-line `asn1parse` utility](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.1/man1/asn1parse.html) and [many, many C functions for reading/writing ASN.1 data.](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.1/man3/).

Answer (score 0):

You do not specify what the encoding is, but the answer is that you cannot, in general, divide up ASN.1 data into pieces without parsing the ASN.1 data.  That is certainly true for PER.  For BER, IF only definite lengths have been encoded, you could parse the length and skip ahead to the next TLV without parsing the current one.  However, unless you are using DER, definite lengths are not required to be used, and any indefinite length would require parsing through the data to find the end markers.  Note that you cannot just merely scan ahead for the end markers, as that same sequence of bytes could appear somewhere as actual data (e.g. in an OCTET STRING).

From your description, where you believe BF 4F 80 80 signifies the start of a record but you believe there are more records than you see starting markers, one possible explanation is that you are using unaligned PER for the encoding and the start of a record is sometimes not byte-aligned.